# How to navigate to a server through Windows command line

Tags: command-line

I'm writing a batch file and have to navigate to a server first. However if it is only a drive I know I can just type in

```
C:\> D:
D:\>

or 
C:\> cd blar
D:\blar\>
```

But now the target location is like: `\\10.0.0.0`

So how can I navigate to it without mapping it to drive D first?

Answer (score 3):

You can refer to the resources in your server as

```
\\10.0.0.0\shareName\blar\doSomething.cmd
```

But if you want to "navigate" to the required point, you need to map to a drive letter.

And here, you have the option to explicitly use `net use` to create the mapping or you can do

```
pushd \\10.0.0.0\share\blar
doSomething.cmd
popd
```

that will assign a drive letter to the share and change the current directory to the indicated folder in the mapped drive. Popd will revert the operation, leaving you in the starting point

Comment: It is actually a .bat file which calls for a python code located in the server. So before running the calling the Python code I need to first make sure the environment is now \\10.0.0.0\share\blar..  it is not .cmd

Comment: @Twinkle, no difference, .cmd, .bat, .exe, change to the desired target, run whatever needs to be run and return to the starting point. If all is done from a batch file, you will still have to `pushd ...`, `python something.py`, `popd`, and the python code will run with the folder used in `pushd` as the current folder.

Comment: I added the pushd and popd line inside my .bat file, before and after calling the python script and it works fine now!